# Resharper says I need to reference a dll, which is already referenced. code compiles ok

Tags: .net, reference, resharper

I have a strange problem with resharper.

I have a project file which is modified so that references are made by using an environment variable like so:

```
<Reference Include="$(DllLocation)My.Companies.dll">
  <Private>false</Private>
</Reference>
```

The project references another project, which also has the reference to the same dll in the same way.

Resharper flags usages of the type from this dll as errors and says Module My.Companies.dll version blah pub key blah should be referenced.

The projects compile fine.  If I modify both projects in the ide by removing the reference and then re-adding the reference to the same file, then the issues go away.

Is there some workaround for this?  I'm using 3.1 and visual studio 2008, although 2005 has same issue.  I'd like to upgrade to 4.5, but not sure the company will pay for it yet.  Will I still have this issue in 4.5?

Comment: I'm still seeing this regularly with ReSharper 6.1.1000.82

Comment: Seeing this as well, with the ReSharper Code Analysis shipped with TeamCity Professional 7.1.1 (build 24074), should be some Resharper version >= 6.1, but don't know the exact version.
Did you create a support issue? Would be nice to link it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ask the ReSharper support.
They may tell you best and are quite friendly.

Comment: I see Ilya post on here quite regularly, so I thought I would try.  plus this is a wider forum, giving others who might have had the same issue the chance to answer, as well as being a place where, if there is an answer, others will be able to find it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

I've not encountered this issue, neither in 4.5 nor 5.0, so I'm guessing it might be fixed.